# Handling files in Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am a complete beginner in Django and I am trying to learn how to add elements to the database from a file. I have three fields in the model and a form.py to add a `FileField` to the models page. Logically, I need to read the data from the file(a plain text file)  and populate the database along with the first two (`drug_name` and `name_type`) leaving the third field empty. All the data in the file should correspond to the single entity from `drug_name` and `name_type`.

from django.db import models

OtherName.py

```
class OtherName(models.Model):
    Name_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        (1, 'RAC1'),
        (2, 'RAC2'),
        (3, 'RAC3'),
        (4, 'RAC4'),

    )
    drug_name = models.ForeignKey('MoleculeDictionary', blank=False, null=False)
    Name_type = models.ForeignKey('NameType')
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, help_text=u'Name for the compound')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.Name_name)
```

Form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms import *
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from django.core.files import File
from app.models.molecule_synonym import OtherName
file_upload = FileField(required=False)

    def handle_uploaded_file(self, file_upload, commit=True):
        file_upload = self.cleaned_data.get('file_upload', None)
        file_upload.seek(0)
        with open('file_upload', 'r') as f:
            model_file = File(f)
            model_file.read()
            names = model_file.__iter__
            form = MoleculeSynonymForm(names)
            if form.is_valid():
                self.instance = form.save(commit=False)
            else:
                raise forms.ValidationError(u"The file contains invalid data.")




    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = getattr(self, "instance", None)
        if instance:
            instance.save()

         # ...do something with extra_field here...
        return super(OtherNameForm, self).save(commit=commit)


    class Meta:
        model = OtherName
```

I don't get error or anything. In fact,  I am not even sure whether the file is being processed or not. Every time I try to save the I get the first (`drug_name`) and second(`name_type`) populated with null values for the Name. I want the data from the file uploaded to the Name column. How should I achieve that? Also, how can I check whether my file is being read or not?
Thanks

Comment: Not related to your question, but try to learn how to use pdb. You then can put statement in between your code so that you can step through and print variables and execute python commands.

Comment: When ever I try to use pdb.set_trace() I get a IO error.